# Storyboard Entry Point Missing

Tags: swift, uistoryboard, xcode7.2

In xcode 7.2 there is no Storyboard Entry Point item in the Object List.
I need to use Storyboard Entry Point , I couldn't find any similar problem by google searches so can anyone help me here.

Answer (score 101):

1. Click on Top of ViewController or Controller in Document Outline window (on left side) of the Controller you want to make Storyboard Entry Point.
2. Click on Attribute inspector button (in right side).
3. Enable "Is Initial View Controller".

Storyboard Entry Point will reappear hopefully.

[image: Storyboard Entry Point]

Answer (score 31):

There is a `Is Initial Controller` checkbox in the Attributes Inspector (<kbd>⌥⌘4</kbd> or <kbd>⌥⌘5</kbd>) of the window controller in Interface Builder

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to have Storyboard Entry Point as an item and exist in Object list

Comment: @Fattie In a storyboard it's still there.

Answer (score 6):

Xcode 11.6, press `⌥⌘5` > enable `Is Initial View Controller`