# Programmatically connecting Storyboard w/ ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I've been SLOWLY learning how to build iOS applications with `Swift` and was sent this article by someone why has been doing it professionally: [A Case For Using Storyboards on iOS](https://medium.cobeisfresh.com/a-case-for-using-storyboards-on-ios-3bbe69efbdf4). Although I have taken the approach of learning how to build iOS application programmatically, I do believe that storyboards have their place in iOS development. I'm trying to implement `Marin Benčević` idea by having a new storyboard for every view w/ its own `ViewController`. However, I'm having issues getting this connected. I continuously run into this same error:

`Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'LoginViewController' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?`

Now my file structure is a little different as I want to keep my views separated from my controllers but its as shown:

[image: file structure]

LoginViewController.swift:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        let vc = LoginViewController.instance()
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let loginStoryboard = LoginViewController()

    self.window?.rootViewController = loginStoryboard
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

UIStoryboardExt.swift:

```
import UIKit

extension UIStoryboard {
    func initialViewController<T: UIViewController>() -> T {
        return self.instantiateInitialViewController() as! T
    }
}
```

UIViewControllerExt.swift:

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    class func instance() -> Self {
        let storyboardName = String(describing: self)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
        return storyboard.initialViewController()
    }
}
```

info.plist:

`Main storyboard file base name: LoginViewController`

All in all, I'm wondering how can I connect a `UIViewController` to a `View.storyboard` programmatically without having to use the property tab of the storyboard. I've tried so many different variations of how to do this but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Here was a `StackOverflow` Question that I also attempted to get working but could not:[StackOverflow](http://let%20storyboard%20=%20UIStoryboard(name:%20%22LoginViewController%22,%20bundle:%20nil)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20vc%20=%20storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:%20%22LoginViewController%22))

**EDIT**

Along with what [Christian Abella](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032290/programmatically-connecting-storyboard-w-viewcontroller/51032825#51032825) said, I did need to also set the class like of the storyboard object[image: Class]

Comment: [Did you set the designated entry point?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45211444/1361672)

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t want to use the properties tab? Its there for, well, a reason. If you are still learning, don’t overcomplicate things for yourself. If you want to get `initialViewController` from a storyboard, one must be marked as such, otherwise the system wouldn’t now what to do. Also, if you did get this to work, presenting `LoginViewController` inside of `LoginViewController.viewDidLoad()` would get you an endless loop of showing the same VC.

Answer (score 2):

This is doable and I do this in some of my projects.
But you need to do the following:

1. Remove all **"As Initial View Controller"** ticks form your storyboard files.
2. In the Apps' Settings go to **General** tab and clear the **Main Interface** from the Deployment Info
3. In the Apps's Setting go to **Info** tab and clear the 'Main storyboard file base name' property.

   ```
     self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

     let main : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

     let loginVC = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController

     self.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
     self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

     return true
   ```

And as @Losiowaty pointed out, your viewDidLoad will cause an endless loop so you need to remove that code the present the *LoginViewController*.

Comment: But then you still cannot get a VC by calling `UISToryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()`, can you? You should rather use `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`, right?

Comment: yep. identifier is needed. please see the sample code that I have added.